# Number of solutions of arithmetic function's equation

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Say, an equation is given below
\begin{equation}
2\pi(x) - \pi(2x)=\omega(x)
\end{equation}
 where $x$ is a positive integer, $\pi(x)$ is the prime-counting function, and $\omega(x)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $x$.  I would like to know if this equation holds for finitely many values of $x$ or infinitely many.

If one uses asymptotic formula (from number theory) it can be written that
\begin{equation}
\omega(x) \sim \ln x / \ln \ln(x)
\end{equation}
(from http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/ant/main3.pdf)
 and 
\begin{equation}
\pi(x) \sim x/\ln(x),
\end{equation}
so the above equation can be rewritten (after simplification) as
\begin{equation}
2x\ln(2)=\ln(x)\ln\ln(x)\ln(2x) +f(x)
\end{equation}
 where $f(x)$ is an error term.

If I plot the left side (which is linear, supposed to be a straight line) and the right side (a curve), assuming $ f(x) $ is 100% accurate, then the equation implies(?!) that the right will intersect left side. Since line can intersect a curve ($ln  $ function) finite times, so there are finite intersection points. So, can I say that there are only finitely many values of $x$?

Comment: There is no asymptotic formula for $\omega(x)$; instead one knows that its maximal order is equal to what you claim. Anyway, one easily sees using the PNT that $2\pi(x) - \pi(2x) \sim 2 (\log 2) x/(\log x)^2$, which proves that there are only finitely many such $x$ satisfying your equation.

Comment: Can you provide some motivation for this?  In particular, if you are analyzing n/d-perfect numbers or some aspect of the distribution of coprimes of an integer, I would be interested to hear and contribute.  Gerhard "Many Of Us Are Interested" Paseman, 2015.03.16

Comment: Not what you mentioned . I had an idea to show "Brocard's problem has finite solution" , current question is a consequence  of that.